# Using λ to define function in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Following function works:

```
(define (testfn)
  (define (contains sl item)    (ormap (λ(x)(equal? item x)) sl))
  (if (contains (list 1 2 3) 2)    "yes" "no"))

(testfn)
```

Output:

```
"yes"
```

But following, which uses λ symbol, does not:

```
(define (testfn2)
  (λ (contains sl item)    (ormap (λ(x)(equal? item x)) sl))
  (if (contains (list 1 2 3) 2)    "yes" "no"))
```

Error is:

```
contains: unbound identifier in module in: contains
```

Can λ symbol be used to define inner (or general) functions which may be called at multiple places?

Comment: `λ` is an alias for `lambda`, not `define`.

Comment: The "λ symbol" is the lowercase Greek character *lambda*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to define it like you would with any other identifier.

```
(define (testfn2)
  (define contains (λ (sl item) (ormap (λ(x)(equal? item x)) sl)))
  (if (contains (list 1 2 3) 2)    "yes" "no"))
```

Your code creates a function but (1) it is not bound to anything and (2) it actually takes three arguments, the first of which is "contains".